# Spring Boot: Dynamically change the static resource handler?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resources

I have the following in configuration for my Spring Boot project that serves static files from the local filesystem:

```
@Configuration
public class StaticResourceConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
    {
        System.out.println("adding resource handler");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/myfiles/**").addResourceLocations("file:///C:/Users/Pepria/Downloads/static_files/");
    }
}
```

Above config works fine but I want to change the resource location dynamically at runtime. As I understand, above code runs before any of my logic executes. How can I go about doing this ?

Comment: Just add the location(s) into a `.properties` file. Inject an `Environment` instance and read the key/value from it before adding the your "locations".

Comment: @ɯıpɐʌ As I mentioned, the resource locations will be read in by one of my java classes which I think will be after this configuration is created...basically, assume I don't know the resource locations when the application is first started but will find out during its runtime. Will your approach work then ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a ResourceHandler with your desired path like this:

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/myfiles/**").addResourceLocations("file:" + Strings.filePath);
```

You can set Strings.filePath in you application at any time.

```
public class Strings {
    public static String filePath;
    //or maybe setters getters
}
```

Comment: Hi can you where should I can add registry.addResourceHandler method in spring boot?